# How to wait for webpage to load before reading lines in R?

Tags: r, redirect, web-scraping

I am using R to scrape some webpages. One of these pages is a redirect to a new page. When I used `readLines` with this page like so

```
test <- readLines('http://zfin.org/cgi-bin/webdriver?MIval=aa-markerselect.apg&marker_type=GENE&query_results=t&input_name=anxa5b&compare=contains&WINSIZE=25')
```

I get the still redirecting page, instead of the final page `http://zfin.org/ZDB-GENE-030131-9076`. I want to use this redirection page because in the URL it has `input_name=anxa` which makes it easy to grab pages for different input names.

How can I get the HTML of the final page?

---

The redirection page: `http://zfin.org/cgi-bin/webdriver?MIval=aa-markerselect.apg&marker_type=GENE&query_results=t&input_name=anxa5b&compare=contains&WINSIZE=25`

The final page: `http://zfin.org/ZDB-GENE-030131-9076`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to wait untill the redirection but in the source code of the web page before the redirection, you can see (in a script tag) a javascript function `replaceLocation` which contain the path where you are redirected : `replaceLocation(\"/ZDB-GENE-030131-9076\")`.

Then I suggest you to parse the code and get this path.
Here is my solution :

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

url <- "http://zfin.org/cgi-bin/webdriver?MIval=aa-markerselect.apg&marker_type=GENE&query_results=t&input_name=anxa5b&compare=contains&WINSIZE=25"

domain <- "http://zfin.org"

doc <- htmlParse(getURL(url, useragent='R'))

scripts <- xpathSApply(doc, "//script", xmlValue)

script <- scripts[which(lapply(lapply(scripts, grep, pattern = "replaceLocation\\([^url]"), length) > 0)]

# > script
# [1] "\n          \n\t    \n\t      replaceLocation(\"/ZDB-GENE-030131-9076\")\n            \n          \n\t"

new.url <- paste0(domain, gsub('.*\\"(.*)\\".*', '\\1', script))

readLines(new.url)
```

`xpathSApply(doc, "//script", xmlValue)` to get all the scripts in the source code.

`script <- scripts[which(lapply(lapply(scripts, grep, pattern = "replaceLocation\\([^url]"), length) > 0)]` to get the script containing the function with the redirecting path.

(`"replaceLocation\\([^url]"` You need to exclude "url" cause there is two `replaceLocation`functions, one with the object url and the other one with the evaluated object (a string))

And finaly `gsub('.*\\"(.*)\\".*', '\\1', script)` to get only what you need in the script, the argument of the function, the path.

Hope this help !